# How to trigger a Model method on every access in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model which needs trigger a method every time data is accessed from it or saved to it. I'm having difficulty figuring out how to trigger the method.

Here's what I've tried:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

    after_initialize :hello
    def hello
        binding.pry
    end
end
```

My understanding is that the after_initialize would trigger whenever this model is accessed, but apparently this is not so. How do I get this to trigger on a call such as this:

```
@instance = MyModel.paginate()
```

Comment: Hey i think you have to used same method calling for two different call back like after_save and after_find. find more on: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is the list of all `callbacks`

```
  after_initialize, after_find, after_touch, before_validation, after_validation,
  before_save, around_save, after_save, before_create, around_create,
  after_create, before_update, around_update, after_update,
  before_destroy, around_destroy, after_destroy, after_commit, after_rollback
```

You can trigger your method with any of these callbacks. See the example

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

   after_find :hello
   after_save :hello
   # call_back goes here ...

   def hello
      binding.pry
   end
end
```

`after_initialize` being triggered after new objects are instantiated, like

```
MyModel.new()
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails does not provide a way that can generally be accessed in such  actions, it does however for single cases, so you could do something like

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    #all cases that wanna include
    before_save :hello
    after_save :hello
    after_initialize :hello
    def hello
        binding.pry
    end
end
```

Check available callbacks from [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)

Answer (score 0):

`after_initialize` is triggered after an instance is created, not when it is accessed. Actually, what does it mean "it is accessed"?

It makes a huge different if you mean whenever any of the object methods are called or when persistence methods are called, etc.

Depending on your need, you may want to use a Proxy object. You can encapsulate your instances in a Proxy that gets the calls, logs whatever you want to log, then calls the object. Otherwise, you will need to override/monkey patch all the methods inside the class, which is definitely not a good idea.

```
@instance = MethodLogger.new(@instance)
@instance.paginate
```